# What's the difference between Sitecore a Droplink and Droplist in the custom item generator tool?

Tags: sitecore

I know both fields only contain single items in Sitecore, but Droplinks store an item's ID and Droplists store an item's display name.

In the coding part, when we get value of Droplist via the custom item generator class, it gives ListItems.  But as I mentioned above, Droplists also contain single items.  So what is the difference and why does the custom item generator class give list items in case of Droplists?  Is it a bug in the custom item generator?

What is the core difference of both fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the Custom Item Generator's patch config, `CustomItem.config`

In that file it maps the **DropList** field type to a multilist wrapper which gives you the `ListItems` property:

```
<FieldMapping fieldType="Droplist">CustomMultiListField</FieldMapping>
```

You should change this part of the config to pull back text, which would be:

```
<FieldMapping fieldType="Droplist">CustomTextField</FieldMapping>
```

Comment: Not bad! Actually, don't use lookup field because it doesn't point to a GUID. Use CustomTextField because it points to an item name.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with CustomTextField!

Comment: Sorry, @Mark I didn't try I am busy with some project release, I'll do it on weekends and let you know

Answer (score 7):

You are correct in your understanding of how Sitecore stores the values for these two different field types. I don't know about the details of the code or module you are using, but here are some example code snippets explaining how this could be done.

**Droplist**

Stores the *Name* of the selected item in the field.
Note that the dropdown list in the Sitecore content editor will display the *Display Name* of the items, but still uses item name internally.
If you want to retrieve the selected item, you could do so as follows:

```cs
Item sourceItem = //code here to get the item selected as the *source* of the template field
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
string selectedName = item["YourDroplistFieldName"];
Item selectedItem = sourceItem.Children[selectedName];
```

**Droplink**

Stores the *ID* of the selected item in the field.
To retrieve this item use the following:

```cs
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
LinkField field = item.Fields["YourDroplinkField"];
Item selectedItem = field.TargetItem;
```

Note, to see how Sitecore stores fields internally you can select the 'View' toolbar and check the 'Raw Values' checkbox (in the content editor).

Generally I would almost always use a **droplink** field over a **droplist**, except when you only need to use the name of the selected item.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed - the `Droplink` store the item ID and the `Droplist` stores only the string representation of the item (item name). There is no way to retrieve the actual item when you are using Droplist. I.e. when using Droplink you have the option to retrieve the TargetItem. Also when renaming the item and previewing the raw values - you can see that in case you are using Droplist - the item selection is no longer available, but the value persists somehow.

Comment: @YogeshSharma this is the core difference. That when using droplink you can retrieve the target item - and when using droplist you have no way of doing that.

Comment: Yes, But why we use Droplist and why Sitecore provides

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right but I am aware with all these things you are saying, I am expecting for some difference like in which case we need to use only Droplist not Droplink, I hope you are getting my point

Comment: @YogeshSharma - you can check this blogpost for more information http://backtocoding.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/sitecore-droplist-vs-droplink/. Basically I am against the usage of Droplist, but you might use it in cases where you are not intrested in the actual item behind the value.

Comment: already did it, you are right, any idea why in code part it gives multilist with custom item generator but it store only single item in Sitecore

Comment: @YogeshSharma - what kind of custom item generator you are using ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58864/discussion-between-nsgocev-and-yogesh-sharma).